# Regex to check if input matches a landline area code

Tags: javascript, regex, phone-number

In Australia we have area codes 02,03,07,08 however when i try to put 04 into the field it allows the form to be submitted when it should not allow it.

I am wondering if anyone knows how to fix this please.

```
function phtest(){
OTHERRegex = /^[07]{2}[0-9]{8}$/
NSWRegex = /^[02]{2}[0-9]{8}$/
VICRegex = /^[03]{2}[0-9]{8}$/
WARegex = /^[08]{2}[0-9]{8}$/
if (document.getElementById('phone2').value != '' || NSWRegex.test(document.getElementById('phone2').value)
        || VICRegex.test(document.getElementById('phone2').value) 
        || WARegex.test(document.getElementById('phone2').value)
        || OTHERRegex.test(document.getElementById('phone2').value))
     alert('Please input correct Landline Phone Field\n');
return false;
else
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you don't enclose the if / else in curlybraces, you close it with semicolons, so the alert closes the if, and the return false does nothing.

```
function phtest(){
    var elem = document.getElementById('phone2');
    if (/^[(02|03|07|08)]{2}[0-9]{8}$/.test(elem.value)) {
        return true;
    }else{
        alert('Please input correct Landline Phone Field\n');
        return false;
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pkehj/4/)

Comment: Or maybe even `/^0[2378][0-9]{8}$/`.

Comment: @Warlock, there were other problems in your logic and regular expressions as well. As an exercise, you might want to add the curlybraces to your code and work it from there.

Comment: @dfsq - I knew there was a way to do that, but regex isn't really my thing, I couldn't get it working without the `|` seperator, thanks!

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I was editing my answer, please review now and put your comments.

Comment: @Warlock - My apologies. I was referring to the code in the original submission and meant to include the submitters name, not yours. I didn't see any problems with your code and in fact upvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed curly braces in your if statement. So, you will get false anyway.

```
 if (document.getElementById('phone2').value != '' ||   NSWRegex.test(document.getElementById('phone2').value)
            || VICRegex.test(document.getElementById('phone2').value) 
            || WARegex.test(document.getElementById('phone2').value)
            || OTHERRegex.test(document.getElementById('phone2').value))
 { 
^^^
     alert('Please input correct Landline Phone Field\n');
     return false;
 }
^^^
else
{
    return true;
}
```

---

I have modified your code, you can try it:

```
function testPattern(phone){
      var OTHERRegex = /^[07]{2}[0-9]{8}$/,
      NSWRegex = /^[02]{2}[0-9]{8}$/,
      VICRegex = /^[03]{2}[0-9]{8}$/,
      WARegex = /^[08]{2}[0-9]{8}$/;

      return (VICRegex.test(phone)
              || WARegex.test(phone)
              || NSWRegex.test(phone)
              || OTHERRegex.test(phone));
}

function phtest(){
  var phone = document.getElementById('phone2').value;
  var isValid = (phone 
                 && phone.length > 0
                 && testPattern(phone));

  if (!isValid) alert('Please input correct Landline Phone Field\n');

  return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It is good for almost all formats - +61255555555, 0255555555, +61 2 5555 5555, +61-2-5555-5555

```
function validateLandline(numberStr) {

    var landlineRegex = /^((00|\+)61|0)(2|3|7|8)\d{8}$/;

    return landlineRegex .test(numberStr.replace(/ /g,'').replace(/-/g,''));
}

validateLandline('+61255555555') // true
validateLandline('+61-2-5555-5555') // true
validateLandline('+61 2 5555 5555') // true
validateLandline('0255555555') // true
validateLandline('02 55555555') // true

validateLandline('+61455555555') // false
validateLandline('0455555555') // false and so on
```